# Is using recursion the easiest solution for N! time complexity algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Let's suppose we have such a problem to solve.
We have coins nominals:

```
0.5g, 1g, 3g, 6g
```

As an example we have `5g` amount of coins. We want to divide `5g` for two searchers who want to have exactly the same amount of coins, but they don't care about the value.

How many possibilities of dividing coins?

---

### First option

```
0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g
```

First searcher gets `5 x 0.5g` coins. Second searcher exactly the same.

### Second option

```
1g, 1g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g, 0.5g
```

First sercher gets `1 x 1g` and `3 x 0.5g` coins.

### Another option

In above options searchers get exactly the same number of coins which is requirement and value of coins which is not necessary. There are more possibilities.

How many possibilities is in dividing the coins for two searchers having `[X]g` coins?

Is the easiest solution for `N!` time complexity algorithm to **use recursion**?

Comment: Yes (I needed 12 more letters)

Comment: There is no absolute truth for which one is simpler / easier (/ faster) for all problems of some complexity, that's something you judge on a per-problem basis and learn with experience. If this is really about this specific coin problem, not all O(n!) problems, and you're looking for a easy or fast solution for that, you might want to [edit] your question and rephrase it appropriately (although **the coin change problem** is fairly well-studied already - it shouldn't be hard to find some information on that online).